# Django DetailView with form for comments

Tags: django, forms

I have this url mapping:

```
url(r'^article/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.ArticleView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
```

and I have this view:

```
class ArticleView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'template/article.html'
    context_object_name = 'article'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = self.object.comment_set.filter(approved=True)
        return context
```

I've already displayed all the approved comments (as you see), but I don't know how to create a comment form inside that ArticleView.
I have this `ModelForm`:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

and... Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The problem with CommentForm is that I don't know how to 'hide' article and approved fields and how to fill article field with the article got in the ArticleView.

I've tried to combine `FormMixin` with `DetailView` but.. when I submit the 
 comment form, console displays: `Method not Allowed (POST)`.
How can I create a form view into ArticleView?

If you didn't get something, please ask me, I know my grammar is bad. I will try to be clear as much as possible.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview

Comment: Ok, Actually I did something, but I have... a problem.
https://i.gyazo.com/8dc8acca8743b9735da2f06628ed6583.png i have that article field and admitted that shouldn't be accessible by user. (see image)

Comment: I can exclude 'admitted' (it's 'approved', actually, but I forgot to change the name), but I don't know how to hide and set value to article field in order to belong to that particular article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a temporary variable like this and you won't have to set an initial value in ArticleView

Simply as this

```
context['form'] = self.get_form()
```

and this

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
           new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
           new_comment.post = self.get_object()
           return super(ArticleView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, kind of..

```
class ArticleView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'template/article.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={
            'article': self.object
        })
        context['comments'] = self.object.comment_set.filter(approved=True)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ArticleView, self).form_valid(form)
```

in `forms.py`:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ('admitted',)
        widgets = {
            'article': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

The only way I could... set a value for that article field (which is a foreign key for the article) was to set initial value in ArticleView.

If someone have a better alternative, I'm glad too see it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been years, but maybe my answer will be useful for someone
Yierstem's answer worked for me, but I made a few changes

First, changed `get_success_url` in order to use parent model's `get_absolute_url`:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

Add `get_absolute_url` method to parent model first:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('record_detail', args=[str(self.pk)]
```

Second, I add my target article and author (ForeignKey(s) of my Comment model) inside `form_valid` method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
    new_comment.target = self.object
    new_comment.author = self.request.user
    new_comment.save()
    return super(RecordDetailView, self).form_valid(form)
```