# Django: DetailView containing reviews. Add a form for reviews with update/create

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Currently I have the following structure.

I have Users, which can be Teachers or Students. Students can leave reviews for teachers. I've set up a detailed view for teachers and added a 'reviews' attribute to `get_context_data` to loop through reviews to display them.

**Aim:** Each user who is a student can submit a review of a teacher. I want to display a form at the bottom of my detailed view. If user already had a review, then we call update. If user doesn't have a review, we create it.

**Models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Student')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    reviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Review(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Student')
    star = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    body = models.TextField()
```

**Views.py**

```
class ReviewSubmitForm(forms.Form):
    star = forms.IntegerField()
    body = forms.CharField()

class TeacherView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Teacher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(TeacherView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add extra context from another model
        context['reviews'] = Review.objects.filter(teacher_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['rating'] = Review.objects.filter(teacher_id=self.kwargs['pk']).aggregate(Avg('star'))
        context['form'] = ReviewSubmitForm()
        return context

class ReviewSubmit(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'users/teacher_detail.html'
    form_class = ReviewSubmitForm
    model = Review

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super(ReviewSubmit, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

I'm now able to see the `form` and use it in my template.

My teacher view is located at `/users/<pk>`

The logic that I'd like is: look for , check current student id.

If there is an entry with pk=pk and student_id = student_id then load update form. Otherwise if it's a student load create form.

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607700/django-detailview-with-form-for-comments) is somewhat similar, but not quite the same.

Edit: **form_template.html**

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    <span color="red">{{ field.errors }}</span>
    <label>
        {{ field.label_tag }}
    </label>
    <div>{{ field }}</div>
</div>
{%  endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to show your form template.

Comment: Added the form, I include it in the teacher_detail.html template using {%  include 'users/form_template.html' %}